# Finding a root by bisection method in Excel

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, math-software

Working on a maths assignment and we're trying to use Excel for a bisection method.

$$\frac12 e^{x/2}+\frac{1}{2x}-\frac32=0$$

Here is a pic, I can't get the formula to work with the exponent.

This is what we've done so far, can anyone spot what we've got wrong with the formula?

[image]

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for formatting formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should read (1/(2*A8)) For the second term

Your current second term reads (1/2 *A8) which means $\frac{1}{ 2} A8$

Comment: Thanks for that, got it sorted now!